# What is the right syntac for `--set-env-vars` in gcloud and `.ps1` file to set multiple env variables when deploying Cloud Functions?

Tags: powershell, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, gcloud

I'm trying to deploy a function using gcloud and powershell.

While doing that I want to set multiple environment variables.

Current script looks like this

```
--set-env-vars folder_id=$FOLDER_ID,SECRET_NAME=$SECRET_NAME,GCP_PROJECT=$PROJECTID
```

And this sets only `'folder_id'` and takes all the strings after the first `=` including the rest of commas and equal signs as its value.

I know I can also use `env-var-file` but as you can see I want these values to be variables people can dynamically set.

What is the right syntax to do this?

So far I've tried,

```
# with quotation mark
--set-env-vars "folder_id=$FOLDER_ID,SECRET_NAME=$SECRET_NAME,GCP_PROJECT=$PROJECTID"
```

```
# with equal from the beginning
--set-env-vars=folder_id=$FOLDER_ID,SECRET_NAME=$SECRET_NAME,GCP_PROJECT=$PROJECTID
```

```
# with quotation mark AND equal from the beginning
--set-env-vars="folder_id=$FOLDER_ID,SECRET_NAME=$SECRET_NAME,GCP_PROJECT=$PROJECTID"
```

```
# with square brackets
--set-env-vars=[folder_id=$FOLDER_ID,SECRET_NAME=$SECRET_NAME,GCP_PROJECT=$PROJECTID]
```

```
# Passing an array of strings
$ENV_VARS = @("folder_id=$FOLDER_ID","SECRET_NAME=$SECRET_NAME","GCP_PROJECT=$PROJECTID")
--set-env-vars=$ENV_VARS
```

Before I would go on the path to parse `env.yml` file from `.ps1` and then execute deploying code, I wanna give it one more shot by asking the question here.

Comment: I once failed to set equal sign within the env var value was forced to use env file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a separate `--set-env-vars` for every variable like
`--set-env-vars folder_id=$FOLDER_ID --set-env-vars SECRET_NAME=$SECRET_NAME`
isn't an elegant solution but it works.

Comment: Thank you, @Andrew. It worked.
The syntax did cross my mind but I was kind of wishing it hadn't been it...

Answer (score 1):

Other solution is:

gcloud functions deploy muy_function 
--region us-east1 
--entry-point muy_function 
--runtime python38 
--source=../path/muy_function/ 
--service-account my_function@my_project.iam.gserviceaccount.com 
--trigger-event google.storage.object.finalize 
--set-env-vars ^:^VAR=VALUE:VAR=VALUE:VAR=VALUE

The -set-env-vars variable has start ^:^ and the variable must be separated by ":"
--set-env-vars ^:^VAR=VALUE:VAR=VALUE:VAR=VALUE